# Hide 'div' after specific amount of time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div, which is generally used for showing some status messsage like "you have selected some xyz thing"

Now, I need to hide it at interval of specific amount of time (say, 60 secs) after page loads.

Code:

```
 <div id="msg">You have selected 'Time and Money' magazine</div>
```

How can I perform the above mentioned thing?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  setTimeout(function () {
      $('#msg').hide();
  }, 60000);
});
```

Comment: this is great. Thanks a bunch, maybe this should be said on the api page, doesnt seem to mention anything about this. a smoother animation is `fadeOut()` however

Answer (score 4):

To hide msg after 60 seconds, do this

```
$("#msg").fadeOut(60000);
```

Comment: thanks, I believe that your are Indian, so I should thanks in typical Indian Style "Dhanyawad"

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you need: [jQuery Timers](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/timers)

```
$(function(){
  $(document).oneTime(60000, function(){
    $('#msg').hide();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) this -

```
$('document').ready(function(){
  window.setTimeout('test()',time in milliseconds);
});

function test(){

  $('#divid').hide();

}
```

Comment: The way you're calling setTimeout, it will use `eval` to evaluate your string (`'test()'`). Instead, using `setTimeout(test, 5000);` will avoid the use of eval, which is unnecessarily inefficient for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's 1.4 [delay function](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)